# How to read Network Logs using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

The application which i'm trying to automate have session time out of 20 mins. For every 20 mins a new `id_token` would be generated in the `'Network'`logs. My desire is to capture that `id_token` response field value and pass it to the URL and run my automation scripts. How can I achieve this using selenium web driver?

please find the below image. I highlighted the response fields which i want to capture and append to the url and run the scripts. These token id's change for every 20 mins.

Image with Token :

[image]